# Not able to format root partition in Arch Linux installation because already labelled

Tags: installation, partition, arch-linux, fdisk, formatting

I am installing Arch Linux on a previously Windows machine. I have created the partitions, with root on sda1, and now I am trying to format it with `mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda1`, but it's not liking that. Apparently the partition already has a label "RECOVERY", and the command doesn't execute with the error: `/dev/sda1 is apparently in use by the system; will not make a filesystem here!`. What is going on and what should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's almost certainly mounted, probably by FUSE as part of a graphical file manager you're using (such as `nautilus`).

You can see what's mounted via the `mount` command. No arguments are required. You'll probably find sda1 in that list along with its mount point. Use `umount /path/to/mount/point` to release it, then feel free to smash it with an `mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda1` command.

It's also possible that you're seeing the block device which contains your Arch installer. Make sure you're not doing that when you look at your mount command. If `/dev/sda1` is mounted to something like `/` or `/boot`, that's not the disk you're looking for.

Comment: Running `mount`, I'm not seeing /dev/sda1.

Comment: If that's the case, post the output of `mount` as well as `lsblk -f` and `blkid`. That should tell what this is.

Comment: Rebooting actually ended up fixing the issue.. Thank you, though.